# SSH Keys Won't allow for me to log into a Ubuntu OpenStack image

Tags: ssh, openstack

I have an instance of the ubuntu image: precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img. I can boot/launch the image from Nova. [Below is the image details] However, I am not able to log into the box with the following command:

```
ssh -i wso2.pem ubuntu@10.10.13.177
```

**I get the error:**

"Permission denied (publickey)."

**Image details:**

```
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Property                            | Value                                                    |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| status                              | ACTIVE                                                   |
| updated                             | 2013-05-21T00:24:34Z                                     |
| OS-EXT-STS:task_state               | None                                                     |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host                | openstackdev01                                           |
| key_name                            | wso2                                                     |
| image                               | Ubuntu Percise (6eaada5b-1d6b-4b30-841e-13099fbaa32a)    |
| private network                     | 192.168.100.2, 10.10.13.177                              |
| hostId                              | 0ce06ae59800f214e6a0170febb2832c85dd008ffcf9d88395dc5e1c |
| OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                 | active                                                   |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name       | instance-00000029                                        |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname | openstackdev01                                           |
| flavor                              | m1.small (2)                                             |
| id                                  | bf6b32a8-13db-44fa-9f31-e76ec2a2e452                     |
| security_groups                     | [{u'name': u'default'}]                                  |
| user_id                             | dcad9335689c471aa8a0cab0ff724573                         |
| name                                | U2                                                       |
| created                             | 2013-05-14T22:22:12Z                                     |
| tenant_id                           | 31cc3e0878534830a02a3981bbcdbf4e                         |
| OS-DCF:diskConfig                   | MANUAL                                                   |
| metadata                            | {}                                                       |
| accessIPv4                          |                                                          |
| accessIPv6                          |                                                          |
| progress                            | 0                                                        |
| OS-EXT-STS:power_state              | 1                                                        |
| OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone         | nova                                                     |
| config_drive                        |                                                          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

My thought is that there is something wrong with OpenStack registering the key with the image. Where would I look to confirm that this is the case? Also, how would I solve this issue? The wso.pem key was generated from the ssh add pair command and contains the RSA private key.

Comment: Try the verbose mode `ssh -i wso2.pem -vvv ubuntu@10.10.13.177` this would give you more information about whats going on

Comment: That was the issue... permission issue on the key. Please make this an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the verbose mode `ssh -i wso2.pem -vvv ubuntu@10.10.13.177` this would give you more information about whats going on